# Drawing two stroke engine in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was trying to reproduce this image:

[image: Screenshot]

I've got the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,snakes}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\tiny\sf,inner sep=0pt}]
%   \draw[red] (.5,-2.155) circle(1);
        \draw[xshift=-.474cm,yshift=.03cm,rotate around={15:(0,0)},very thick] (-.25,-1.6) arc(130:476.6:1);

        \draw[white,xshift=-.474cm,yshift=.03cm,rotate around={15:(0,0)},ultra thick] (-.25,-1.6) arc(130:465.5:1);

        \draw[rotate around={30:(.3,-1.58)},xshift=.23cm,yshift=-1.6cm] (0,0) arc(180:270:.6) arc(0:-180:.7) arc(270:360:.6) arc(180:0:.1);
        \fill[black,radius=.05] (.5,-2.25) circle;

            \draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) to[bend right] (0,1) -- cycle;
            \draw[fill=white] (.6,.45) arc(-10:190:.1) --+ (-.35,-2) arc(150:380:.1) -- cycle;

                \fill[black,radius=.05] (.5,.45) circle;
                \fill[black,radius=.05] (.14,-1.58) circle;
%       \draw (.19,-1.6) arc(0:-90:.5) arc(180:370:.7) to[bend left=45] (.39,-1.6);
            \draw[thick,rounded corners] (1,.2) -- (1,1.5) -- (0,1.5) -- (0,.4);
            \draw[thick] (.013,.4) -- (-.2,.4) arc(90:180:.1) --+ (0,-1.9);

            \draw[xshift=-.474cm,yshift=.03cm,rotate around={15:(0,0)},very thick] (-.25,-1.6) arc(130:406.5:1);

            \draw[thick] ($([xshift=.5cm,yshift=-2.155cm]0,0)+(130:1)$) --+ (0,1.5) arc(-180:-270:.1) --+ (.04,0) -- ($([xshift=.5cm,yshift=-2.18cm]0,0)+(120:1)$);

            \draw[thick] ($([xshift=.5cm,yshift=-2.155cm]0,0)+(60:1)$) --+ (0,.3) --+ (.5,.3);
                \coordinate (h) at ($([xshift=.5cm,yshift=-2.155cm]0,0)+(60:1)$);
                \coordinate (a) at ($(h)+(0,.3)+(.5,0)$);
            \draw[thick] ([yshift=.2cm]a) --+ (-.5,0) --+ (-.5,.8) --+ (.4,.8) --+ (.4,.6) --+ (-.2,.6) arc(90:270:.2) --+ (.6,0) --+ (.6,-.2) -- cycle;
            \draw[thick] (1,.2) --+ (.9,0) --+ (.9,.2) --+ (.2,.2);
                \draw[thick,xshift=.01cm,decorate,decoration={snake,segment length=5mm}] (1.2,.4) --+ (0,1.51);
                \draw[thick,decorate,decoration={snake,segment length=5mm}] (1.2,1.9) --+ (-1.81,0);
                \draw[thick,decorate,decoration={snake,segment length=5mm}] (-.6,1.9) --+ (0,-1.508);
            \draw[thick] (-.6,.405) --+ (-.2,0) arc(90:180:.1) --+ (0,-1.6) to[bend right=20] (-1,-1.5) --+ (0,-2) --+ (3,-2) --+ (3,0) to[bend right=20] (1.9,-1.3) --+ (0,.31) --+ (-.5,.31);

            \draw[xshift=.4cm,yshift=1.5cm,rounded corners=2pt] (0,0) rectangle (.2,.3);
%           \draw[xshift=.4cm,yshift=1.77cm] (0,0) parabola[parabola height=.4cm] (.2,0);
            \draw[xshift=.4cm,yshift=1.77cm] (.2,0) --+ (-.05,.4) arc(0:180:.05) -- (0,0);
            \draw[fill=white,xshift=.4cm,yshift=1.77cm] (-.05,0) rectangle (.25,.15);
            \draw[rounded corners=1pt,xshift=.45cm,yshift=1.5cm] (0,0) --+ (0,-.05) --+ (.1,-.05);

            \node (a) at (2.7,.1) {Auspuffkanal};
            \draw (a.west) --+ (-.4,0);
                \node (a) at ([yshift=-1cm]2.7,.1) {Ansaugkanal};
                \draw (a.west) --+ (-.4,0);
            \node (a) at ([yshift=-2.5cm]2.7,.1) {Kurbelwelle};
            \draw (a.west) --+ (-1.3,0);
                \node (b) at (1.8,1) {Kolben};
                \draw (b.west) --+ (-.8,-.3);
            \node (c) at (1.3,2.1) {Zündkerze};
            \draw (c.west) --+ (-.4,0);
                \node (n) at (-2,-2.4) {Kurbelgehäuse};
                \draw (n.east) --+ (1.2,0);
            \node (n) at ([yshift=1.5cm]-2,-2.4) {Pleuelstange};
            \draw (n.east) --+ (1.9,0);
                \node (n) at ([yshift=2.3cm]-2,-2.4) {Überströmkanal};
                \draw (n.east) --+ (1.15,0);
            \node (e) at (-1.5,1.25) {Zylinder};
            \draw (e) --+ (1.2,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]

My questions are:

- How to draw the "Zylinder" like in the reference picture?
- How can my messy code be improved/ cleaned up?

Comment: Off-topic: `\sf` is decades obsolete. If you are using 2e, you shouldn't be using these obsolete switches.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this comes close to the shape you are looking for. I constructed this using `arc` with a fixed radius.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\tiny\sffamily,inner sep=0pt}]


               % Zylinder section
               \begin{scope}[red]
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\S}{0.105} %Segment radius
              \draw[thick,xshift=.01cm] (-.25,1.75) coordinate (ZtopL) arc (180:0:\S) arc (0:180:-\S) arc (180:0:\S) arc (0:180:-\S) arc (180:0:\S) arc (0:180:-\S)  arc (180:0:\S) coordinate (ZtopR);
              \draw [thick] (ZtopR) arc (0:90:-\S) coordinate (ZR);
              \draw [thick] (ZtopL) arc (0:-90:\S) coordinate (ZL);
              \draw[thick,xshift=.01cm] (ZL)   arc (-90:90:-\S) arc (90:-90:\S)  arc (-90:90:-\S) arc (90:-90:\S)  arc (-90:90:-\S) arc (90:-90:\S) coordinate (ZLbot) ;
               \draw[thick,xshift=.01cm] (ZR)  arc (90:-90:\S) arc (-90:90:-\S)   arc (90:-90:\S) arc (-90:90:-\S)   arc (90:-90:\S) arc (-90:90:-\S) coordinate (ZRbot) ;
               \end{scope}

             % Lines that connect to the Zylinder          
            \draw[thick] (ZLbot) --+ (-.2,0) arc(90:180:.1) --+ (0,-1.6) to[bend right=20] (-1,-1.5) --+ (0,-2) --+ (3,-2) --+ (3,0) to[bend right=20] (1.9,-1.3) --+ (0,.31) --+ (-.5,.31);
             \draw[thick] (1,.2) --+ (.9,0) |- (ZRbot);


%   \draw[red] (.5,-2.155) circle(1);
        \draw[xshift=-.474cm,yshift=.03cm,rotate around={15:(0,0)},very thick] (-.25,-1.6) arc(130:476.6:1);

        \draw[white,xshift=-.474cm,yshift=.03cm,rotate around={15:(0,0)},ultra thick] (-.25,-1.6) arc(130:465.5:1);

        \draw[rotate around={30:(.3,-1.58)},xshift=.38cm,yshift=-1.6cm] (0,0) arc(180:270:.6) arc(0:-180:.7) arc(270:360:.6) arc(180:0:.1);
        \fill[black,radius=.05] (.65,-2.25) circle;

            \draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) to[bend right] (0,1) -- cycle;
            \draw[fill=white] (.6,.45) arc(-10:190:.1) --+ (-.2,-2) arc(150:380:.1) -- cycle;

                \fill[black,radius=.05] (.5,.45) circle;
                \fill[black,radius=.05] (.29,-1.58) circle;
%       \draw (.19,-1.6) arc(0:-90:.5) arc(180:370:.7) to[bend left=45] (.39,-1.6);
            \draw[thick,rounded corners] (1,.2) -- (1,1.5) -- (0,1.5) -- (0,.4);
            \draw[thick] (.013,.4) -- (-.2,.4) arc(90:180:.1) --+ (0,-1.9);

            \draw[xshift=-.474cm,yshift=.03cm,rotate around={15:(0,0)},very thick] (-.25,-1.6) arc(130:406.5:1);

            \draw[thick] ($([xshift=.5cm,yshift=-2.155cm]0,0)+(130:1)$) --+ (0,1.5) arc(-180:-270:.1) --+ (.04,0) -- ($([xshift=.5cm,yshift=-2.18cm]0,0)+(120:1)$);

            \draw[thick] ($([xshift=.5cm,yshift=-2.155cm]0,0)+(60:1)$) --+ (0,.3) --+ (.5,.3);
                \coordinate (h) at ($([xshift=.5cm,yshift=-2.155cm]0,0)+(60:1)$);
                \coordinate (a) at ($(h)+(0,.3)+(.5,0)$);
            \draw[thick] ([yshift=.2cm]a) --+ (-.5,0) --+ (-.5,.8) --+ (.4,.8) --+ (.4,.6) --+ (-.2,.6) arc(90:270:.2) --+ (.6,0) --+ (.6,-.2) -- cycle;

             \draw[xshift=.4cm,yshift=1.5cm,rounded corners=2pt,fill=white] (0,0) rectangle (.2,.3);
%         \draw[xshift=.4cm,yshift=1.77cm] (0,0) parabola[parabola height=.4cm] (.2,0);
            \draw[xshift=.4cm,yshift=1.77cm] (.2,0) --+ (-.05,.4) arc(0:180:.05) -- (0,0);
            \draw[fill=white,xshift=.4cm,yshift=1.77cm] (-.05,0) rectangle (.25,.15);
            \draw[rounded corners=1pt,xshift=.45cm,yshift=1.5cm] (0,0) --+ (0,-.05) --+ (.1,-.05);


            \node (a) at (2.7,.1) {Auspuffkanal};
            \draw (a.west) --+ (-.4,0);
                \node (a) at ([yshift=-1cm]2.7,.1) {Ansaugkanal};
                \draw (a.west) --+ (-.4,0);
            \node (a) at ([yshift=-2.5cm]2.7,.1) {Kurbelwelle};
            \draw (a.west) --+ (-1.3,0);
                \node (b) at (1.8,1) {Kolben};
                \draw (b.west) --+ (-.8,-.3);
            \node (c) at (1.3,2.1) {Z\"{u}ndkerze};
            \draw (c.west) --+ (-.4,0);
                \node (n) at (-2,-2.4) {Kurbelgeh\"{a}use};
                \draw (n.east) --+ (1.2,0);
            \node (n) at ([yshift=1.5cm]-2,-2.4) {Pleuelstange};
            \draw (n.east) --+ (1.9,0);
                \node (n) at ([yshift=2.3cm]-2,-2.4) {\"{U}berstr\"{o}mkanal};
                \draw (n.east) --+ (1.15,0);
            \node (e) at (-1.5,1.25) {Zylinder};
            \draw (e) --+ (1.2,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is really nice! Can this be used (with help of `pgf-core`) as a style; e.g. `\draw[circles] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1);`?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that sorry. Feel free to create a MWE and ask another question on the site. Maybe someone else can help.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to draw a continuous path and probably to avoid decorations. The easiest way I'm aware of is to use `hobby`. Then you can just specify the points you need.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,hobby}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\tiny\sffamily,inner sep=0pt}]
  \draw[xshift=-.474cm,yshift=.03cm,rotate around={15:(0,0)},very thick] (-.25,-1.6) arc(130:476.6:1);

  \draw[white,xshift=-.474cm,yshift=.03cm,rotate around={15:(0,0)},ultra thick] (-.25,-1.6) arc(130:465.5:1);

  \draw[rotate around={30:(.3,-1.58)},xshift=.38cm,yshift=-1.6cm] (0,0) arc(180:270:.6) arc(0:-180:.7) arc(270:360:.6) arc(180:0:.1);
  \fill[black,radius=.05] (.65,-2.25) circle;

  \draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) to[bend right] (0,1) -- cycle;
  \draw[fill=white] (.6,.45) arc(-10:190:.1) --+ (-.2,-2) arc(150:380:.1) -- cycle;

  \fill[black,radius=.05] (.5,.45) circle;
  \fill[black,radius=.05] (.29,-1.58) circle;
  %       \draw (.19,-1.6) arc(0:-90:.5) arc(180:370:.7) to[bend left=45] (.39,-1.6);
  \draw[thick,rounded corners] (1,.2) -- (1,1.5) -- (0,1.5) -- (0,.4);
  \draw[thick] (.013,.4) -- (-.2,.4) arc(90:180:.1) --+ (0,-1.9);

  \draw[xshift=-.474cm,yshift=.03cm,rotate around={15:(0,0)},very thick] (-.25,-1.6) arc(130:406.5:1);

  \draw[thick] ($([xshift=.5cm,yshift=-2.155cm]0,0)+(130:1)$) --+ (0,1.5) arc(-180:-270:.1) --+ (.04,0) -- ($([xshift=.5cm,yshift=-2.18cm]0,0)+(120:1)$);

  \draw[thick] ($([xshift=.5cm,yshift=-2.155cm]0,0)+(60:1)$) --+ (0,.3) --+ (.5,.3);
  \coordinate (h) at ($([xshift=.5cm,yshift=-2.155cm]0,0)+(60:1)$);
  \coordinate (a) at ($(h)+(0,.3)+(.5,0)$);
  \draw[thick] ([yshift=.2cm]a) --+ (-.5,0) --+ (-.5,.8) --+ (.4,.8) --+ (.4,.6) --+ (-.2,.6) arc(90:270:.2) --+ (.6,0) --+ (.6,-.2) -- cycle;
  \draw[thick] (1,.2) --+ (.9,0) --+ (.9,.2) --+ (.2,.2);
  \draw [thick,magenta] (1.2,.4) to [quick curve through={ ++(-.1,.2) ++(.2,.2) ++(-.2,.2) ++(.2,.2) ++(-.2,.2) ++(.2,.2) ++(-.2,.2) (1.2,1.845)  ++(-.15,.15) ++(-.15,-.15)  ++(-.15,.15)  (.69,1.845) }] (.65,1.845) (.35,1.845) to [quick curve through={  (.31,1.845)  ++(-.15,.15) ++(-.15,-.15)   ++(-.15,.15) ++(-.15,-.15)   ++(-.15,.15) ++(-.2,-.15) (-.6,1.845) ++(.1,-.1) ++(-.2,-.2) ++(.2,-.2) ++(-.2,-.2) ++(.2,-.2) ++(-.2,-.2) ++(.2,-.2)}]  (-.6,.4);
  \draw[thick] (-.6,.405) --+ (-.2,0) arc(90:180:.1) --+ (0,-1.6) to[bend right=20] (-1,-1.5) --+ (0,-2) --+ (3,-2) --+ (3,0) to[bend right=20] (1.9,-1.3) --+ (0,.31) --+ (-.5,.31);

  \draw[xshift=.4cm,yshift=1.5cm,rounded corners=2pt] (0,0) rectangle (.2,.3);
  \draw[xshift=.4cm,yshift=1.77cm] (.2,0) --+ (-.05,.4) arc(0:180:.05) -- (0,0);
  \draw[fill=white] (.35,1.77) rectangle (.65,1.92);
  \draw[rounded corners=1pt,xshift=.45cm,yshift=1.5cm] (0,0) --+ (0,-.05) --+ (.1,-.05);

  \node (a) at (2.7,.1) {Auspuffkanal};
  \draw (a.west) --+ (-.4,0);
  \node (a) at ([yshift=-1cm]2.7,.1) {Ansaugkanal};
  \draw (a.west) --+ (-.4,0);
  \node (a) at ([yshift=-2.5cm]2.7,.1) {Kurbelwelle};
  \draw (a.west) --+ (-1.3,0);
  \node (b) at (1.8,1) {Kolben};
  \draw (b.west) --+ (-.8,-.3);
  \node (c) at (1.3,2.1) {Zündkerze};
  \draw (c.west) --+ (-.4,0);
  \node (n) at (-2,-2.4) {Kurbelgehäuse};
  \draw (n.east) --+ (1.2,0);
  \node (n) at ([yshift=1.5cm]-2,-2.4) {Pleuelstange};
  \draw (n.east) --+ (1.9,0);
  \node (n) at ([yshift=2.3cm]-2,-2.4) {Überströmkanal};
  \draw (n.east) --+ (1.15,0);
  \node (e) at (-1.5,1.25) {Zylinder};
  \draw (e) --+ (1.2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: smoother path]

Obviously, you'll want to tweak it a bit and presumably won't want magenta, but, hopefully, this should get you started.

Personally, I would avoid all the shifts on paths in the code. These just confuse me, since apparently absolute coordinates are somewhere else and for no obvious reason. However, that may just be a matter of taste, so I only changed the ones I actually needed to understand.

Not a matter of taste: `\sf` is decades obsolete. It ought not be used in LaTeX 2e. (And some classes no longer support it period.)

`snakes` is also deprecated, though much more recently so.

Comment: The `Kurbelwelle` is off-center and also the upper `magenta` part is asymmetric! `Zündkerze` should be placed on the vertical axis of the drawing.

Comment: @AboAmmar I just put it where you had. You asked how to draw the Zylinder, so that's the part I drew. If you want it to be centred, obviously you have to put the other bits differently. As for its being asymmetric, as I already said, you will need to adjust the points to get the result you want. I'm showing you how to do that. I'm not doing everything for you. You just change the points the curve passes through and the start and end points to whatever you want them to be.

Comment: @AboAmmar Presumably, your Auspuffskanal should end further to the right or, else the line on the other side should end further to the right. Otherwise the line won't join the existing lines if it is centred. Anyway, please yourself.